# cuke4nuke server is not resposding

Tags: cucumber

While running cuke4nuke for a c# dll, I am getting application crash message and stop working.

Error Details:

```
Daily_Transform_Member_Employment.dll -q -c |d:\wac
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/rubygems-update-1.8.0.gemspec:11.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/rubygems-update-1.8.0.gemspec:11.
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon) to get coloured output on Windows
Feature: emplperiod

  Scenario: DataBase and Schema names
Unable to contact the wire server at localhost:3901. Is it up? (Cucumber::WireSupport::Connection::ConnectionError)
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/wire_support/connection.rb:51:in `socket'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/wire_support/connection.rb:35:in `send_data_to_socket'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:67:in `timeout'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/wire_support/connection.rb:35:in `send_data_to_socket'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/wire_support/connection.rb:19:in `call_remote'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/wire_support/request_handler.rb:10:in `execute'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/wire_support/wire_protocol/requests.rb:109:in `execute'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/wire_support/wire_protocol.rb:34:in `begin_scenario'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/wire_support/wire_language.rb:43:in `begin_scenario'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/wire_support/wire_language.rb:43:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/wire_support/wire_language.rb:43:in `begin_scenario'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:18:in `before'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:107:in `send'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:107:in `fire_hook'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:106:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:106:in `fire_hook'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:103:in `before'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:94:in `before_and_after'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:78:in `with_hooks'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:115:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:115:in `around'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:13:in `around'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:95:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:95:in `execute_around'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:12:in `around'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:114:in `around'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:112:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:112:in `around'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:90:in `around'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:77:in `with_hooks'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:51:in `accept'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:106:in `with_visitor'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:45:in `accept'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:51:in `visit_feature_element'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:164:in `broadcast'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:50:in `visit_feature_element'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:40:in `accept'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:39:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:39:in `accept'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:20:in `visit_feature'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:164:in `broadcast'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:19:in `visit_feature'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:29:in `accept'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:17:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:17:in `each'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:28:in `accept'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:14:in `visit_features'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:164:in `broadcast'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:13:in `visit_features'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:45:in `run!'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/cucumber:14
C:/Ruby187/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
C:/Ruby187/bin/cucumber:19
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've bumped into a .Net Framework compatibility issue.
That's the message that appears while trying to run Cuke4Nuke on Framework 4.0.

According to http://cuke4ninja.com/sec_hello_world_net.html, you should revert to Framework 3.5

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same error.
But everything worked after I disabled my Firewall.